# BCNF Decomposition algorithm not working

Tags: decomposition, bcnf

I have the following problem: R(ABCDEFG) and F ={ AB->CD, C->EF, G->A, G->F, CE ->F}. Clearly, B & G should be part of the key as they are not part of the dependent set. Further, BG+ = ABCDEFG, hence candidate key. Clearly, AB->CD violates BCNF. But when I follow the algorithm, I do not end up in any answer. Probably doing something wrong. Can anyone show me how to apply the algorithm correctly to reach the decomposition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should calculate a canonical cover of the dependencies. In this case it is:

```
{ A B → C
  A B → D
  C → E
  C → F
  G → A
  G → F } >
```

Since the (unique) candidate key is `B G`, no functional dependency satisfies the BNCF. Then, starting from any functional dependency `X → Y` that violates the BCNF, we calculate the closure of `X`, `X+`, and replace the original relation `R<T,F>` with two relations, `R1<X+>` and `R2<T - X+ + X>`. So, chosing in this case the dependency `A B → C`, we replace the original relation with:

```
R1 < (A B C D E F) ,
     { A B → C
       A B → D
       C → E
       C → F} >
```

and:

```
R2 < (A B G) ,
     { G → A } >
```

Then we check each decomposed relation to see if it satisfies the BCNF, otherwise we apply recursively the algorithm.

In this case, for instance, in `R1` the key is `A B`, so `C -> E` violates the BCNF, and we replace `R1` with:

```
R3 < (C E F) ,
     { C → E
       C → F } >
```

and:

```
R4 < (A B C D) ,
     { A B → C
       A B → D } >
```

two relations that satisfy the BCNF.

Finally, since `R2` too does not satisfy the BCNF (beacuse the key is `B G`), we decompose `R2` in:

```
R5 < (A G) ,
     { G → A } >
```

and:

```
R6 < (B G) ,
      { } >
```

that are in BCNF.

So the final decomposition is constituted by the relations: `R3`, `R4`, `R5`, and `R6`. We can also note that the dependency `G → F` on the original relation *is lost* in the decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation. I still have a confusion. When you get the decomposition to R1 and R2, the FD : G- >F seems to have disappeared. This is where I was getting confused to start with. Is that OK to drop some of the FDs, while decomposition? My understanding on this is very unclear. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Rana, as I said in my last sentence of the answer: “We can also note that the dependency G → F on the original relation is lost in the decomposition.” In fact it is possible that in a decomposition obtained by the algorithm for BCNF some dependency is lost. This is a negative fact, in the sense that we have lost an important information about the original schema (an integrity constraint, as functional dependencies can be seen as integrity constraints).

Comment: For this reason the 3NF (Third Normal Form) can be used instead of the BCNF, since its decomposition algorithm guarantees that no dependencies are lost (but sometimes the result has still some anomalies, like redundancy). In fact this is a well known fact in normalization theory, and for this reason in practice is used the 3NF, not the BCNF.