# Is this in BCNF?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Assume that the relation is obtained through decomposition from a relation with attributes ABCDEFGHI and that dependencies over ABCDEFGHI are listed below.

R(A,B,F)
B->E
A->F

We need to convert this relation into BCNF

What i have done till now is

R1(AB)
R2(AF)
R3(BE)

Is there anything more I should do? Is this proper BCNF or am I missing something?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong (or right). See hits googling 'stackexchange homework.

Answer (score 0):

This answer follows from the edited question, under the following hypotheses:

1. the original relation is R(ABCDEFGHI)
2. a cover of the functional dependencies holding on it is `{B->E, A->F}`

Of course if my hypotheses are wrong the answer is wrong!

In this case:

1. the only candidate key of the original relation is `ABCDGHI`;
2. in the decomposed relation `R1(ABF)` the only non-trivial dependency that holds is `A -> F`, so the relation has the only candidate key `AB`;
3. the relation is not in BCNF, and a decomposition in BCNF is `{R2(AF), R3(AB)}`

Note that you cannot decompose a relation adding an extraneous attribute, like `E` in your decomposition.

Comment: Thank you for your input sir.But i'm a bit confused about it not being BCNF. Is there an algorithm I could follow to convert it to bcnf?

Comment: There are algorithm described more or less formally in books on databases. A sketch of an algorithm is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803509/2382734).